# Creating Dynamic Controllers in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement like my controller name will be coming from database like below

http://www.mysite.com/ParkName

I'm using ASP.Net mvc3

I'm not getting any perfect solution how to route that dynamic controller or do in better way.

Could any one please Guide me.

Comment: You should have a look a the `ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entity Web Application`. This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) gives you a guide.

Comment: What i need is the {controller} portion of the url determined from my database column. How to handle that? When i click above url it should show appropriate park for the users.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `DefaultControllerFactory` to search controller type base on database name.

There is a simple [example on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434647/Controller-lookup-and-default-controller-factory)

Comment: I created a Class called DynamicControllerFactory and wrote following

public class DynamicControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory { private readonly IServiceLocator _Locator;

Comment: And? You still have problem?

Comment: Right now i can redirect to the action but it gives the issue when displaying view. It  throws error like
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: